# Interesting projects based on Distributed/Operating Systems

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, virtual-machine, distributed-system

I would like to know some interesting challenges based on distributed systems that could be solved within the time frame of a quarter (my university follows quarter system!). I am hoping to work on a single project that would satisfy both an Operating Systems course as well as a Distributed Systems course so that I would have plenty of time to work on it (as I have taken both courses!). I am looking for a strong programming component. Could anybody point me in the right direction? I know Hadoop/map-reduce is the hot stuff but I would appreciate it if someone suggested solvable challenges in the field of virtual machines.

Answer (score 1):

MIT has an OCW class, "Distributed Computer Systems Engineering," with a [Projects Section](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-824-distributed-computer-systems-engineering-spring-2006/projects/) which you might find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Check this blog entry on [Mapreduce & Hadoop Algorithms in Academic Papers (5th update – Nov 2011)](http://atbrox.com/2011/11/09/mapreduce-hadoop-algorithms-in-academic-papers-5th-update-%E2%80%93-nov-2011/). The problem areas in the blog entry could also be solved using non-MapReduce distributed algorithms also.

I suggest instead of going with the hype, pick a topic of your interest and work on it.